# Powershell force Onedrive sync at Logout

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to enforce, at logout for each user, a method to dehydrate Onedrive and synced sharepoint sites via Onedrive.  I effectively got the file flags to change with a user logoff script via our Domain controller. The file flags change, but the files will not dehydrate until the next login.  I would like to keep the VHDX profiles small by dehydrating at logoff.  I've attempted to give it a start-sleep for 30 and I've also tried starting Onedrive in the script, but I could use some help with the last phase of the script to determine how to initialize the sync before the logoff process is complete.

```
$FilesAndFolders = .{

    get-childitem $env:userprofile\<COMPANY> -Force -File -Recurse | where Attributes -eq 'Archive, ReparsePoint'

    get-childitem $env:userprofile\<COMPANY> -Force -Directory -Recurse | where Attributes -eq 'Directory, Archive, ReparsePoint'

}


$FilesAndFolders | foreach {attrib.exe $_.fullname +U -P /s /D}


#List all Files locally synced and For each file change the attributes to U (Unpinned) and removed P (Pinned attribute)
get-childitem $env:OneDriveCommercial -Force -File -Recurse | where Attributes -eq 'Archive, ReparsePoint' | foreach {attrib.exe $_.fullname +U -P /s}


start $env:userprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

kill -name Onedrive -force

exit
```

Comment: Doesn't OneDrive require a user context in order to be used (eg, for licensing reasons)?  Performing this action during user logoff may be tricky/risky.  If successful, it may incur some support calls (eg, "Hey, how come my logoff is hanging?")  IMO, I'd move this to on-idle processing, or during screensaver startup.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  So this is a AVD environment, so space is limited thus the desire to perform this as the user logs off.  I have a script that forces logoff on idle/disconnected users.  This is where I see this script being effective.  As for the user context, you may be right, and this is worth looking into.  I was hoping that Onedrive would still be currently logged in upon running the logoff script.  If that's not the case, then I need to find another way to force the sync prior to the logoff.  Currently I have users syncing when they log back in....